# SQL Server : create error how to write database name with the table name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE DATABASE agom COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
CREATE TABLE Branches
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE agom.Brands
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE agom.Work_Order
(
NUMBER INT NOT NULL,
BRANCHID INT NOT NULL,
BRANDID INT NOT NULL,
WDATE DATE NOT NULL,
REPAIRSTATUS VARCHAR(255),
REPAIRCOST VARCHAR(255),
REMARK VARCHAR(500),
PRIMARY KEY (NUMBER,BRANCHID,BRANDID)
)
CREATE TABLE agom.Profiles
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
USERNAME    VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
PASS        VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
 )
 ALTER TABLE agom.Work_Order
 ADD CONSTRAINT branchfk
 FOREIGN KEY (BRANCHID) REFERENCES Branches(ID)

 ALTER TABLE agom.Work_Order
 ADD CONSTRAINT brandfk
 FOREIGN KEY (BRANDID) REFERENCES Brands(ID)
```

I get an error that cannot create table 
I try to write database name with the table name db.tablename but it's not working
I need to create the database then create the tables and its constraints but I don't know where is the error.I am a sql noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never `Database.Table`.

It's either `Table`, or `Schema.Table`, or `Database.Schema.Table`, or `Server.Database.Schema.Table`.

You probably just want to insert [`USE agom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx) right after `create database`, and then only refer to tables by name.

Alternatively, you can refer to your tables as `agom.dbo.Work_Order`, `dbo` being the default database schema.

See [Using Identifiers As Object Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for general reference.

Comment: @AhmedKato By putting that line right after your `create database` statement. See the link I've added.

Comment: this is my code
CREATE DATABASE USE agom COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
CREATE TABLE  agom.dbo.Branches
but it tell me database agom does not exist
and error near USE

Comment: @AhmedKato Then also make the `create` statement a [separate batch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx): `CREATE DATABASE agom COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS; GO`.